# How to replace last occurrence of a substring in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database

How can I replace the last occurrence of a substring with blank string in MYSQL?I could not find any such direct function in MYSQL

**String:** "American Corp National Corp"

**Search String:** "Corp"

**Expected output:** "American Corp National"

Could anyone suggest?

Comment: trim(trailing substring_index(the_string, ' ', -1) from the_string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select reverse(concat(
               left(reverse('American Corp National Corp'),
                    instr(reverse('American Corp National Corp'),reverse('Corp'))-1),
               substr(reverse('American Corp National Corp'),
                      instr(reverse('American Corp National Corp'),reverse('Corp'))+
                      length('Corp')))) result
```

([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/014de/24))

Answer (score 7):

This is shorter and more readable:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING 'Corp' FROM 'American Corp National Corp')
```

Comment: Only works if there is nothing after the last `Corp` - so the supplied example works, but if the main string is `American Corp National Corporeal` then the output is `American Corp National Corporeal`, rather than `American Corp National oreal`.

Answer (score 1):

After researching this problem myself and reading the answers above, I created the following function to solve this problem. In my case, I needed to change the last separator in a sequence, so that e.g., "Aap, Noot, Mies" would become "Aap, Noot & Mies":

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `change_last_substring`(
    input_string text,  
    separator_old tinytext, 
    separator_new tinytext
) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

set @output_string=
trim(
    leading separator_new from
    concat
    (
        left(input_string,length(input_string)-length(substring_index(input_string,separator_old,-1))-2),
        separator_new,
        substring_index(input_string,separator_old,-1)
    )
);

RETURN @output_string;

END
```

Comment: I used this equivalent but deterministic and more compact version: `CREATE FUNCTION replace_last(in_str text, old tinytext, new tinytext) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4 DETERMINISTIC BEGIN RETURN trim(LEADING new FROM concat(left(in_str, length(in_str) - length(substring_index(in_str, old,
-1)) - 1), new, substring_index(in_str, old, -1))); END`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an SQL-query:

```
select CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('<TEST_STRING>','<String that you want to replace>',(length('<TEST_STRING>') - length(replace('<TEST_STRING>', '<String that you want to replace>', '')))),'<String to be replaced>',SUBSTRING_INDEX('<TEST_STRING>', '<String that you want to replace>', -1)) as test
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like an awful way to do it, but... `reverse` the string, search for the first occurence of the `reverse` of the search string using `locate`, then calculate what index that would be in the non reversed string?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length (Pretty sure you need to use this instead of length to be unicode compliant, but check to be sure!)

Worked example:

String: 0123456789 (char_length = 10)

Search string: 567 (char_length = 3)

Reverse string: 9876543210

Reverse search string: 765

Locate returns index = 2

index of end in real string = 7 (char_length(string) - 1 - index -> 10 - 1 - 2)

index of start in real string = 5 (char_length(string) - 1 - (char_length(search string) - 1) - index -> 10 - 1 - (3 - 1) - 2)

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15543587) doesn't replace `@FROM` with `@TO`, it replaces `@FROM` with empty string. If you need to replace `@FROM` with `@TO`, here is a modification of that answer:

```
SELECT reverse(
           concat(
               concat(
                   left(reverse(value),
                        instr(reverse(value), reverse(@FROM)) - 1),
                   @TO
                 ),
               substr(reverse(value),
                      instr(reverse(value), reverse(@FROM)) +
                      length(@FROM))))
FROM `table`
WHERE `value` like '%' + @FROM + '%'
```

Notice additional `WHERE`value`like '%' + @FROM + '%'`, as this removes an extra character if the substring doesn't occur in the value, e.g. trying to replace "a" with "b" in "ccc" results in "cc"

Answer (score 0):

More easy and reliable

```
CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('American Corp National Corp','Corp',2), "REPLACE_STRING" ,SUBSTRING_INDEX('American Corp National Corp','Corp',-1))
```

> REPLACE_STRING you can change it with replace string or empty for replacing.

Comment: only works if it has 2  Corp

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of [MySQL (>= v8)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) / [MariaDB (>= v10.0.5)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/), you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace the last occurrence of `needle` with `replacement`, like so:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(haystack, "^.*needle", "\\1replacement")
```

This exploits the greediness of `*`.

If you are using MySQL, and know (or can calculate) the number of occurrences, you can use [the optional `occurence` parameter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) of `REGEXP_REPLACE`.