# Replace the last comma with AND in GROUP_CONCAT mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve data from MySQL tables and format it like "Bruno, Phil Sturgeon and Simon".  Specifically, I want to concatenate all the values with a commas except the last one, which I want to concatenate with "and".

Right now I can only get all values concatenated by commas.  How can I replace the last instance with "and" instead?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
   b.title,
   GROUP_CONCAT(a.name ORDER BY name SEPARATOR ',') AS name                   
FROM `book` AS b
LEFT JOIN `book_authors` AS ba
  ON b.id = ba.book_id
INNER JOIN `author` AS a
  ON a.id = ba.author_id
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY b.title
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want "Franklin, Watson, and Crick" as the representation of three particular authors?  If so, that's something you should do in your app rather than trying to do it in the dbms.

Comment: Doubly so because your choice seems to be omitting the Oxford Comma. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma

Comment: Take a look at this (it's about replacing the last occurrence of substring) This would work for you as long as you know name will not have a comma (ie/ replace the last occurance of the comma with an and): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543204/how-to-replace-last-occurrence-of-a-substring-in-mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Take the values up to the last comma,CONCAT your 'AND' then add the last value

```
SELECT
   b.title,
  CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(a.name ORDER BY name SEPARATOR ','),',',length( GROUP_CONCAT(a.name ORDER BY name SEPARATOR ','))-length(replace( GROUP_CONCAT(a.name ORDER BY name SEPARATOR ','),',',''))),
              ' AND ',SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(a.name ORDER BY name SEPARATOR ','),',',-1)) AS name                   
FROM `book` AS b
LEFT JOIN `book_authors` AS ba
  ON b.id = ba.book_id
INNER JOIN `author` AS a
  ON a.id = ba.author_id
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY b.title
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/44322) it is hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

An optimized solution with *"user defined variables"*, `CONCAT` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function.
This will invoke `GROUP_CONCAT` at once and the further actions will be performed only with variable `@name`:

```
SET @name = "";
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(@name, LENGTH(@name) - LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,',',-1))-1), ' and ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ',', -1)) name, title
FROM
(SELECT
   b.title as title,
   @name:= GROUP_CONCAT(a.name ORDER BY name SEPARATOR ',') AS name                   
FROM `book` AS b
LEFT JOIN `book_authors` AS ba
  ON b.id = ba.book_id
INNER JOIN `author` AS a
  ON a.id = ba.author_id
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY b.title) as t;
```